# std::vector inconsistent crash between push_back and insert(end(),x)

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, vector

Put this code into MS Visual C++ 2010, compile (debug or release), and it will crash for the insert() loop, but not the push_back loop:

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>

using std::vector;
using std::string;

int main()
{
   vector<string> vec1;
   vec1.push_back("hello");

   for (int i = 0; i != 10; ++i)
      vec1.push_back( vec1[0] );

   vector<string> vec2;
   vec2.push_back("hello");

   for (int i = 0; i != 10; ++i)
      vec2.insert( vec2.end(), vec2[0] );

   return 0;
}
```

The problem is that both push_back() and insert() take the new item by reference,
and when the vector is realloced for more space, the new item becomes invalidated BEFORE it is inserted.

GCC should also have this problem.  I have not checked Clang, but it depends which STD library it is using.

MSVC2010 has some extra code in push_back() that detects if the new item is actually an item within the vector.  If so, it records the item's index and uses that to insert the item after memory has been alloced (instead of using the now-invalidated reference) -- uses _Inside(_STD addressof(_Val))

Is MSVC's extra code non-standard?

My concern is that I am not sure in what code I may have done something like vec.push_back(vec[1]); or vec.insert(it, vec[2]);
I'd have to look through hundreds if not thousands of lines of code that use push_back and insert, and that is just my own code... 3rd party libraries could also be affected.

I assume that GCC could be made to die in horrible ways using this technique (I see no extra code to handle this case, but valgrind didn't detect it in my simple example so will be harder to test),

How best to detect and avoid making this mistake?

Is MSVC2010's extra push_back() code non-standard?  Should MSVC instead detect and assert when it finds vectors used in this way? (ie the secure-computing initiative)

I am thinking of hacking MSVC2010 and GCC's headers to detect these cases.

any other ideas?

Thanks,
Paul

PS: note also that this usage is perfectly fine (and efficient) IF you can guarantee that the vector does not need to be resized

Comment: Code works fine under g++ 4.6. Valgrind did not detect any issues either.

Comment: works fine under MSVC 2012 RC.

Comment: Seems to work without crashes with GCC and with clang too. Does crash in MSVS 2010, I can confirm that.

Comment: I just found this exact bug, fixed in MSVC 2011 and 2012 : http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/735732

Comment: I think "hacking MSVC2010 and GCC's headers to detect these cases" is a terrible idea.  If your code base indeed has "hundreds if not thousands of lines of code that use push_back and insert", you are most likely part of a team, and others will not see your hacks because it is part of the standard library, not your own code.  Besides, a compiler update could blow your changes away.

+1 for the link to MS bug.

Comment: I ended up hacking the headers (first to detect, later to fix if required), because its only required for MSVC 2010 so I just have to detect and work around cases where it was used until MSVC 2012.  Ideally, MS would release patches for such bugs.  And plus, I can document the hack.  Its in a complex compile environment so there is already a long procedure for compiling all the various required libraries.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok, I installed Win8 + MSVC2012 on virtualbox to try it out.  Geez Windows 8 is annoying with the mouse, no buttons to push just hovering which is hard to do with a screen-in-a-window.

The results are interesting and still inconsistent IMHO.

MSVC 2010: the bug comes from the move-semantics, as ecatmur suggested.

The problem is that v.insert(v.end(),v[0]); will select the insert(it, T && val) method, which  is wrong on two fronts:
1) it could lead to the destruction of v[0]. It does not seem to, which suggests to me that the const& reference is preserved and the new version is created via copy rather than move.
and 2) the code path does not make a copy of val before resizing the vector.

Note that the problem was not noticed sooner due to extra code (hacks?) in push_back(&&) - see further commentary at the bottom in relation to MSVC2012.

(note that insert(it,const&) will correctly copy the new item first before resizing the vector, so if the right method was selected there would have been no problem at all).

In MSVC 2012, this is fixed via correctly selecting the insert(it, const T & val) method,
HOWEVER you can still see that push_back() has some extra code to "fix" incorrect usage.

Consider this test:

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>

using std::vector;
using std::string;

int main()
{
   vector<string> vec1;
   vec1.push_back("hello");

   for (int i = 0; i != 1000; ++i)
   {
       string temp = vec1[0];
      vec1.push_back( std::move(vec1[0]) );
   }

   vector<string> vec2;
   vec2.push_back("hello");

   for (int i = 0; i != 1000; ++i)
   {
       string temp = vec2[0];
      vec2.insert( vec2.end(), std::move(vec2[0]) );
   }

   return 0;
}
```

In both cases, std::move() is used to force the && move methods to be chosen.
In both cases, the code should cause catastrophe and hopefully crash.

However, in MSVC 2012, the push_back() loop works fine, because there is some extra code in push_back(&&) that detects if _Val is in the same address space as the vector, and if so will make a copy rather than move.
But, what if the new item was not strictly in the same memory space but still part of the original vector (eg pimpl pointer) ?  I can imagine ways to make push_back(&&) die like it should.

Surely this is not actually necessary, if the programmer says std::move() then that's what should happen, right?  The extra check is surely using some unnecessary CPU cycles.

The insert() loop does not have this hack, which also means that using std::move() incorrectly will only cause corruption SOMETIMES.  Personally I'd prefer fast-fail over fail-only-when-you-are-demonstrating-to-the-client.

So... solutions...

1. Do not use v.insert(v.end(), v[0]) or similar.  This is an unreasonable requirement, as 3rd party code (eg Boost, VTK, QT, tbb, xml libraries, etc etc) may be using that somewhere in their millions of lines of code.
   All the 3rd party libraries I use, I recompile, so whatever my code suffers with, they suffer too.
2. Upgrade to MSVC 2012 RC.  I'll have to wait till it goes Gold, then it will work as expected (with new and exciting bugs in other parts).
3. Hack the headers to detect usage.  I've done that, but the only time the detection works is when the code is actually run.
4. Hack the headers to fix insert(&&).  (and recompile ALL of the libraries/projects - sigh).
   The easiest approach would be to simply comment out the insert(&&) variant (and then we are back to pre-C++11 performance).
   Another approach is to use the same push_back(&&) hack, although I don't see that as a reliable approach.  Perhaps push_back(&&) should also be commented out.

**Further update:**
I fixed the headers.  Turned out to be simple...

MSVC2010's insert(&&) declaration looks like this:

```
template<class _Valty>
iterator insert(const_iterator _Where, _Valty&& _Val)
```

MSVC2012's insert(&&) removed the template part and now looks like this:

```
iterator insert(const_iterator _Where, _Ty&& _Val)
```

So I simply removed the templated _Valty from MSVC2010's insert() and now the correct method is chosen.  It now also matches how push_back(&&) is declared (ie no template on the parameter).
There are still templated parameters for emplace*(&&) methods, but there is no const& confusion there.

Answer (score 2):

Edit: initially I was under the impression that inserting an existing element could be undefined behaviour; I no longer believe that it is, for the following reason:

Per [How to insert a duplicate element into a vector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10218223/how-to-insert-a-duplicate-element-into-a-vector) there is no language in the standard to prohibit inserting a reference to an existing element.  The language referring to invalidation of iterators and references can only be read (in the absence of other indication) as referring to the behaviour after the operation has completed.

Note that per [The behavior of overlapped vector::insert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1329181/the-behavior-of-overlapped-vectorinsert?rq=1) it is specified that the iterator arguments to `insert(it, first, last)` shall not be iterators into the sequence; the absence of any such language on `push_back` implies that a reference into the sequence is specifically allowed (by the legal principle of *inclusio unius est exclusio alterius*).

Looking at the bug report you linked, I'd guess that MSVC's crashing on this case was a result of their code breaking in the presence of C++11 move semantics and was not intended.  g++ handles this case by (I think) copying the inserted element into the appropriate place in the newly allocated memory, *before* copying/moving the existing elements in:

```
void insert(it, const T &t) {
    if (size() + 1 > capacity()) {
        T *new_data = (T *) malloc(sizeof(T) * capacity() * 2);
        new (&new_data[it - begin()]) T(t);
        // move [begin(), it) to [new_data, &new_data[it - begin()])
        // move [it, end()) to [&new_data[it - begin() + 1], &new_data[size() + 1])
    }
    ...
}
```

Rather than hacking the headers, you could instead wrap `std::vector` with your own class template.  If you're going to modify the standard implementation, beware that you don't break code that takes care to ensure that a reallocation will not happen:

```
v.reserve(v.size() + 1);
v.push_back(v[0]);
```

Comment: Thanks for this.  I have a feeling that the standards committee would've thought this particular problem through, hence the question.   Re wrapping vector, I have thought about it and done it before, but I have to reimpl all the constructors AND adjust all the code that directly uses std::vector, so I was looking to avoid that.   This seems like such a serious problem that I figured something must have been done about it before.

Comment: Comment on edit: I am not sure its related to the move semantics.  The bug will still occur if its simply passed by const reference, AND the new item is not copied before the vector is resized.   I am trying to look at MSVC 2012's vector header, and I do not see any extra code to fix the bug, so I am confused.

Answer (score 1):

Answering my own question here,

I found a bug report that is near-identical to my code:
http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/735732

Its apparently fixed in MSVC 2012 as reported in comment above.

I checked deeper into the GCC code, it mentions here that could be related:
00326           // The order of the three operations is dictated by the C++0x
00327           // case, where the moves could alter a new element belonging
00328           // to the existing vector.  This is an issue only for callers
00329           // taking the element by const lvalue ref (see 23.1/13).

But there are too many #ifdefs for me to figure out exactly what its doing.

So I guess the answer is to upgrade to MSVC 2012, or at least hack the headers so I know where else I need to be careful.

Comment: Note that I do not yet consider the issue closed, as I do not understand how MSVC 2012 has fixed the bug.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the implementation of 4.4, both `push_back` and `insert` when they need to grow the buffer call `_M_insert_aux` that grows the buffer, copies the new element first (which means that aliasing is not an issue, since at this point the original object have not been touched) and then all of the previously existing elements. So the implementation is fine.

As of the part of the standard, there is no restriction on aliasing, so the code is compliant and there should not by undefined behavior.

Comment: Thanks for looking at the GCC headers, I thought I could see some copies in there.  In reality, I guess it must ALWAYS make a copy before a resize, as while the new item may not be an item in the vector, it could be a member of an item and thus still be invalidated anyway during a resize.  MSVC's approach is to only copy if the new element's address falls within the range of the vector's memory.  I wonder if that is enough to guarantee correctness?

Comment: @user92979: It depends what code is controlled by that test. I cannot really tell without looking into the source code.